# How to formulate an email with information from a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to send an email based on expired items. I have read through a lot of blogs and found one that finally worked (link below). I had it working last night and now somehow I have broken it. I tried reverting but I am still having issues. I am very new at all this so I really appreciate any explanations you can give. For now I want it to just send an alert because there is a limit on the number of emails it will send daily.

```js
function emailAlert() {
   // Same variations.
  
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  // 2 months from now
  var oneMonthFromToday = new Date(todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay);
  var oneMonthMonth = oneMonthFromToday.getMonth() + 2;
  var oneMonthDay = oneMonthFromToday.getDate();
  var oneMonthYear = oneMonthFromToday.getYear();

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Exp");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 500; // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];    
    
    
    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[5]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

    //email Information
    var subject = 'Pantry Item Needs Attention!';
    var message1 =
      row[6] + ' ' + row[3] + ' of ' + row[2] + ' ' + row[1] + ' will expire on ' + expireDateFormat + '. Item can be found in ' + row[7]
       + '. Please Remove and Replace Item.' + 
      '\n' + 'Thanks Steve!';
      
    var message2 =
      row[6] + ' ' + row[3] + ' of ' + row[2] + ' ' + row[1] + ' will expire on ' + expireDateFormat + '. Item can be found in ' + row[7] + 
      '. Please ensure item has been replaced, removed from the pantry, and deleted from inventory.' +
      '\n' + 'Thanks Steve!'

    //expiration date information
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(row[5]).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(row[5]).getDate();
    var expireDateYear = new Date(row[5]).getYear();

    //checking for today
    if (
      expireDateMonth === todayMonth &&
      expireDateDay === todayDay &&
      expireDateYear === todayYear
    ) {
    
       ui.alert(message1);
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: It's broken is not a very good description of the problem.  Are you getting errors?  Have you viewed executions? Have you looked at the console.log on your browser?  What have you done to identify the problem?

Comment: I meant I am not receiving the alert message. I haven't received any errors, and I know to open my error log and that's about it so far. Like I said still very new, I apologize. I have mostly just been researching similar functions in hopes I'd notice something off about mine.

Comment: This is the same post continued from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764014/comparing-dates-in-google-sheets-script-editor/61764442?noredirect=1#comment109274901_61764442

Comment: If it's running all the way through without an error message, that means the code is working. It's likely that you aren't meeting all the criteria in your if Statement. try `logger.log(expireDateMonth); logger.log(todayMonth); Then run the code. Go to View->Logs and see if expireDateMonth actually equals todayMonth

Comment: I'm not sure what this means but it looks like this...
[20-05-13 15:38:26:916 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:918 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:920 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:921 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:924 EDT] 6.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:925 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:927 EDT] 6.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:929 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:931 EDT] 6.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:933 EDT] 5.0
[20-05-13 15:38:26:935 EDT] NaN

Comment: It means the first time the script went over Logger.log(expireDateMonth), the variable expiredDateMonth was equal to 5. and that occured at [20-05-13 15:38:26:916 EDT]. It is logging the values of your variable. "NaN" means Not a Number

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function emailAlert() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Exp");
  var startRow=2; 
  var rg=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var expireDateFormat=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,new Date().getDate()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")
  var data=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
    var row=data[i];    
    var subject='Pantry Item Needs Attention!';
    var message1=row[6] + ' ' + row[3] + ' of ' + row[2] + ' ' + row[1] + ' will expire on ' + expireDateFormat + '. Item can be found in ' + row[7] + '. Please Remove and Replace Item.' + '\n' + 'Thanks Steve!';
    var message2=row[6] + ' ' + row[3] + ' of ' + row[2] + ' ' + row[1] + ' will expire on ' + expireDateFormat + '. Item can be found in ' + row[7] + '. Please ensure item has been replaced, removed from the pantry, and deleted from inventory.' + '\n' + 'Thanks Steve!';
    Logger.log(message1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it again. I made some changes

Comment: I ran a log, my expiration year is formatting to 120.0. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I was using getYear, which has been replaced by getFullYear. Everything is functioning well now. Thank you guys!

```js
    expireDateYear = new Date(row[5]).getYear();
    
expireDateYear = new Date(row[5]).getFullYear();
```